# Customize a MenuItem´s background in the ActionBar

Tags: android, android-actionbar, menuitem

I need to change the color of a menuItem in an ActionBar (that list that appear when the user press a menuItem in my Action Bar).

Which element of the `android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar` I have to change?

Which `style` I'll have to create to change the `android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure you can do that for a particular menuItem, but you can have a look on a more complete blog post about Styling the ActionBar : [Part 1](http://blog.stylingandroid.com/archives/1240) and [Part 2](http://blog.stylingandroid.com/archives/1249)

Edit : after looking at the articles another time, I think what you want to do is not possible. The best thing is to create an icon with the appropriate color of your menuitem and to change it when you want.

**menu.xml :**

```
<item android:id="@+id/my_menu_item"
android:icon="@drawable/my_menu_item_icon_color1"
android:title="@string/my_menu_item"
android:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
```

**in your activity :**

```
/**
 * Create default menu and keep it in a private var
 */
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
    mMenuActionBar = menu;
    return true;
}


/**
 * Method changing your item to second icon
 */
private void updateActionBar() {
    if (mMenuActionBar != null) {
        MenuItem menuItem = mMenuActionBar.findItem(R.id.my_menu_item);
        if (menuItem != null) {
            menuItem.setIcon(@drawable/my_menu_item_icon_color2);
            invalidateOptionsMenu();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Care to write a summary here?

Comment: I added a more detailed solution